# My close button is going out of the dialog box in sp modal dialog

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sp.ui.modaldialog.showmodaldialog

[image]My close button is going out of the dialog box.

So can I change or align the position of button in SP UI Model Dialog?

Comment: Do you have any custom css added on the page where you are using SP modal dialog?

Comment: No Iam just calling it by onclick of an image